# Автозавершение текста в TextBox по подстроке

Tags: c++, winforms, textbox

Мне понадобилось найти функцию, которая отображает подсказки в TextBox в виде списка подходящих строк (т.е. выпадающий список).

Сейчас для этого использую [`TextBox.AutoCompleteMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
this->textBox1->AutoCompleteCustomSource->AddRange(gcnew array< System::String^  >(3) { L"ДонНТУ", L"ДЭГИ", L"ДонНУ" });
this->textBox1->AutoCompleteMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoCompleteMode::Suggest;
this->textBox1->AutoCompleteSource = System::Windows::Forms::AutoCompleteSource::CustomSource;
```

Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо изменить то, как выбираются подсказки. Сейчас при вводе текста отображаются только строки, которые начинаются на введенные символы. Нужно, чтобы в подсказки выводились и строки у которых вводимые символы в середине или в конце.

После продолжительного поиска эту функцию так и не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за функция или где ее искать. Или подскажите другое решение проблемы.

Comment: О каком окошке в `TextBox` идет речь? Можете скриншот и/или пример кода показать?

Comment: Имеется ввиду окошко выпадающего списка.
![скриншот](C://D//1)
@default locale

Comment: может `ComboBox`? Вставьте ссылку на скриншот и код в текст вопроса.

Comment: Нет. Cписок выпадает из TextBox-a. Вот ![Скриншот](https://www.slickpic.com/organizer/albums/AntonYakubovskiy/Rabota/14216010/2/).
А вот код, позволяющий появляться этому списку:
    // textBox1
    //  
    this->textBox1->AutoCompleteCustomSource->AddRange(gcnew array< System::String^  >(3) { L"ДонНТУ", L"ДЭГИ", L"ДонНУ" });

    this->textBox1->AutoCompleteMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoCompleteMode::Suggest;

    this->textBox1->AutoCompleteSource = System::Windows::Forms::AutoCompleteSource::CustomSource;
@default

Comment: Так яснее. Вставьте это все в вопрос (кнопка «править» под вопросом)

Comment: По существу: стандартного способа написать подсказки по подстроке (а не по префиксу) нет. Народ в английской версии пишет свой механизм подсказок. Код компонента на C# можете посмотреть здесь, надеюсь поймете идею и сможете адаптировать на C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437002/winforms-c-sharp-autocomplete-in-the-middle-of-a-textbox